# maven-release-plugin fails to release:prepare

Tags: maven, mercurial, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm using mercurial, maven and maven-release-plugin to make a release. While executing task `release:prepare` it fails with the following stack trace:

```
[INFO] Transforming 'producer'...
[INFO] Not removing release POMs
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] EXECUTING: /bin/sh -c cd /home/dir/producer && hg branch
[DEBUG] version-1.1
[INFO] EXECUTING: /bin/sh -c cd /home/dir/producer && hg outgoing
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:16.923s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 30 16:00:45 MSK 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/207M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project producer: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project producer: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException:     An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.checkin(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.performCheckins(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCommitDevelopmentPhase.runLogic(ScmCommitDevelopmentPhase.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.execute(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at     org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:277)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.hg.HgScmProvider.checkin(HgScmProvider.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.AbstractScmProvider.checkIn(AbstractScmProvider.java:415)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.checkin(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:156)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.hg.HgUtils.differentOutgoingBranchFound(HgUtils.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.hg.command.checkin.HgCheckInCommand.executeCheckInCommand(HgCheckInCommand.java:66)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.checkin.AbstractCheckInCommand.executeCommand(AbstractCheckInCommand.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:59)
    ... 33 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,     please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

After running:

```
mvn -X clean release:prepare
```

- mvn version: Apache Maven 3.0.4
- hg version: Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.0.2)
- maven-release-plugin version:

  ```
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  ```

I've spent several hours.. Found nothing relevant to my case and completely stuck. Looks like it fails to execute hg outgoing, but after it fails I can execute hg outgoing with no problems.

What is even more weird is that **I could successfully run it on another machine** with the same hg and mvn versions.

The only difference I found is that on first box I have `Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS` and on the second `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS`. Is it the problem of Ubuntu 12.04.5 ? Hopefully not. But then it's so weird.